# How to change images used in app when user select particular theme?

Tags: android, themes, android-theme

I want to achieve the theme functionality in my android application . I want to apply the theme in my android app, when user select the particular theme .

I used lots of images in my android application . How can i change those images dynamically when user select the theme ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is make an array for the images title and id, for examples:

```
private static final String[] TITLES = {"Image 1", "Image 2", "Image 3"};
private static final int[] RESIDS = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};
```

Then you can use them in codes.